# simplexml_load_file return error message 'failed to load external entity "Auth_requestError 200Error"'

Tags: php, xml, curl, file-get-contents

allow_url_fopen = "ON"

I'm trying to read XML response of Telenor API by using simplexml_load_file() but its not working its return 
"failed to load external entity "Auth_requestError 200Error"

May be it is because of late response form Telenor API so I tried with timer but facing same issue

```
function simplexml_load_file_from_url($url, $timeout = 5){
  $opts = array('http' => array('timeout' => (int)$timeout));
  $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
  $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  if(!$data){
    trigger_error('Cannot load data from url: ' . $url, E_USER_NOTICE);
    return false;
  }
  return simplexml_load_string($data);
}

$url = "https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=234234234234&password=4234234234234234324234";
$response = simplexml_load_file_from_url ($url);
 if($response && substr($response->response,0,5)!=="Error")
 {
return $response->data;
}
```

Comment: This rather sounds like you are supposed to provide some sort of authorization credentials with your request, but failed to do so.

Comment: Yes but when I am using correct username and pass then I got only "failed to load external entity"

Comment: So what does $data contain in that case then?

Comment: it should return content of that url

Comment: So far, so obvious, duh. I wanted to know what it _actually_ contains. Checking that variables actually contain what you (often naively) _assume_, is one of the most basics steps of the debugging process.

Comment: Actually I am getting data tag value from this url https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=234234234234&password=4234234234234234324234

Comment: Still not what I asked about. Again: What does `$data` _actually_ contain? Make a debug output to verify reading the content behind that URL actually worked.

Comment: $data contains XML response, I am not handling that url, that url belongs with Telenor and I am using Telenor API, please check my code from question detail, now I edited that. @04FS

Comment: Well that API seems to require some form of authentication, which you are currently apparently not providing.